# Can I add getJSON's done()-functions by callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asynchronous

On this code:

```
 function hello(){
     alert("hello");
 }
 function hi(){
     alert("hi");
 }

 jQuery.getJSON('foo.bar',function(data){
     if (data.foobar) {
         this.done(hello);
     }
     alert('callback done');
 }).done(hi);
```

and assuming this returns from `foo.bar`

```
{"foobar":true}
```

I like to have the alerts in this order:

1. callback done
2. hi
3. hello

But I can not add a `done()`-function in the `success`-callback.

Have you a hint how I add a `done()`-function inside of the `success`-callback?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It looks like a complete mess of program flow going in every different direction. Could you give us a concrete example of the use case you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jqXHR` object is the third argument to the callback function:

```
jQuery.getJSON('foo.bar', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    if (data.foobar) {
        jqXHR.done(hello);
    }
    alert('calback done');
}).done(hi);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be trying to combine callbacks and `done()` handlers in the first place, let alone interweaving them like this. Just use one `done()` handler:

```
jQuery.getJSON('foo.bar').done(function (data) {
    hi();
    if (data.foobar) {
        hello();
    }
});
```

Or if you are worried about a failure in `hi()` preventing the rest from executing, you can pass them to `done()` separately:

```
jQuery.getJSON('foo.bar').done(hi, function (data) {
    if (data.foobar) {
        hello();
    }
});
```